# How to Schedule Run query hourly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have MSSQL Server Express 2014 Edition. Is it possible to schedule a query to be run by hourly?
As I want it to clean up the audit trail records.

Please kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a native way in Express Edition to do this, since the SQL Server Agent isn't available in that edition.

You'll likely need to use a 3rd party application, or write a small program that can be scheduled via Windows Task Scheduler (or some other scheduling tool outside of your SQL Server instance), that executes the SQL you want to use.

The Audit feature stores its data in files on disk. So even if you could schedule a T-SQL SQL Server Agent Job, it would probably be best to do this process all with application code instead, anyway.